# ArrayList.addAll() calls toArray() internally - should I add collections myself?

Tags: java, arraylist

I looked at the source to ArrayList.addAll() and it calls toArray() on the passed in collection.

Wouldn't it be faster, and use less memory, if I iterate over the collection and add the objects one at a time? Especially if I can first create the ArrayList with the needed initial size?

Comment: `System.arraycopy` tends to be super fast. Don't assume another way would necessarily be faster.

Comment: `ArrayList` is backed by an array, so, `addAll` ensures that it's internal array is able to contain the incoming content and performs an `arraycopy`, which I'm pretty sure would be faster then iterating the `List` manually. The only significant issue would be if the size of the incoming `List` is larger then the capacity of the current `List`, as this causes another `arraycopy` operation (after the internal array is resized)

Comment: It's the toArray() call that worries me. Looking at the source I think it's making a copy of the data.

Comment: It's a shallow copy. Should be very cheap.

Comment: Also, this implementation allows you to call `myList.addAll(myList)` without getting into an infinite loop. That might be part of the reason it is implemented that way.

Comment: @khelwood Or without throwing a CME.

Comment: @shmosel That too